# Android Broadcast Receiver Not Working

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to make my app print something to log when screen is turned on but it doesn't work as I expected.

Here is what I have in my Manifest file

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity ...>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <receiver android:name="PhoneBroadcastReceiver" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

and my receiver looks like

```
public class PhoneBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public PhoneBroadcastReceiver()
{
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context _context, Intent _intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String a = _intent.getAction();


    MessageHandler.log("Received action: " + a); // just a wrapper for printing to a log

}
```

}

but it prints nothing to the log. I keep pressing my Android power button and the screen turns on / turns off but my message doesn't appear in the log. What am  I missing? It looks the same as in examples I found on the web.

Comment: Have you tried first to log something to the console of DDMS to see if it's really entering your broadcastReceiver? (with `Log.info("PhoneBroadcastReceiver ","Entering broadcast receiver")`. If you can see this log to the console then, the problem is in your MessageHandler class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot listen for `ACTION_SCREEN_ON` broadcasts via a `BroadcastReceiver` registered in the manifest. You have to register it via `registerReceiver()` from a running component. There are fairly few broadcasts with this trait (`ACTION_SCREEN_OFF`, `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED`, and perhaps `ACTION_USER_PRESENT`).

Answer (score 1):

ACTION_SCREEN_ON won't work if registered via manifest file. You need to register it dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you forget to register the service on

`<application>` tag:

`<service android:name=".YourService" />`