# ACTION_USER_PRESENT in manifest with BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-manifest, broadcastreceiver

There seems to be different opinions on whether it is possible to catch the ACTION_USER_PRESENT screen unlock through the manifest.

This thread implies no it can't be done:

[Android Broadcast Receiver Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698716/android-broadcast-receiver-not-working)

This thread implies yes it can be done:

[Broadcast Receiver for ACTION_USER_PRESENT,ACTION_SCREEN_ON,ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7619696/1007614)

I'm not able to get the event working with either a 2.3.3 or 3.2 emulator.

Does anyone else have recent experience with this?  And perhaps a code sample to share?

Answer (score 10):

Use a receiver:

```
public class Receive extends BroadcastReceiver {

if (intent.getAction() != null) {
            if
                    ( intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)) {
Intent s = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                    s.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                    context.startActivity(s);
}}
```

And in your manifest:

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".Receive"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: i used above your code but first time my lock activity is open but i don't know after that it automaticlly call wallpaper dialog when screen on.why this dialog open instead of my lock activity when screen on...please help quickly thanks...

Comment: I would not use `android:exported="false"` which is also not allowed at a `<intent-filter>`-Tag, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29081414/why-wont-this-broadcast-receiver-work-in-lollipop#comment58423396_29274695

Answer (score 2):

The official document says:

> Beginning with Android 8.0 (API level 26), the system imposes
> additional restrictions on manifest-declared receivers.
>
> If your app targets Android 8.0 or higher, you cannot use the manifest
> to declare a receiver for most implicit broadcasts (broadcasts that
> don't target your app specifically). You can still use a
> context-registered receiver when the user is actively using your app.

so only [some exception](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions) can receive implicit, manifest-defined events.

**Short answer:**
so it's not possible anymore to declare it in the manifest. but it's available by context-registering.